# define the queryset of ModelMultipleChoiceField in the widget

Tags: django, widget, admin

I'm using ModelMultipleChoiceField with a large number of objects.
I want to show only the selected objects and let the user remove a choice with js.
To add choices the user will open a popup similar to ManyToManyRawIdWidget.

I can limit the queryset to the selected choices in the **init** of the form with:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    super(FormName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field_name'].queryset = self.instance.field_name
```

But this will require manual setting on every form.
Is it possible to extend the ModelMultipleChoiceField to get the queryset from the field choices? 
I think that I need to extend ModelChoiceIterator but couldn't understand how to access the module instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

i am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you want the same "list-shuttle" than in auth/user/permissions you should try this;

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Category.objects.all(),
        widget = admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
                _('myfield'), False),
        required = False,
    )

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   form = MyForm
```

Comment: if you want to use this outside of the admin app, you can use the widget, but ensure to import the admin-javascripts in your template

Comment: Thanks! I had trouble figuring this out from the Django docs.