# Define ModelForm Queryset for Custom Widget outside __init__

Tags: python, django

**Background:** I've been working on integrating admin-type "AddAnother" popup functionality (see [this tutorial](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2012/12/more-relatedfieldwidgetwrapper-the-popup/)) for foreign keys in my ModelForm. I've got everything working properly, I'm just not sure if my code is as concise/DRY as it could be.

Here's my ModelForm (Donors belong to Pools, which are managed by Companies):

```
class DonorCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Donor
        widgets = {
            'pool': CustomRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
                Select(), reverse_lazy('company:pool-create'), True)
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DonorCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pool'].queryset = Pool.objects.all()
```

My question is: is there a way to assign a `queryset` to a custom widget outside `__init__` and without overriding the field? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347985/define-the-queryset-of-modelmultiplechoicefield-in-the-widget) did so by overriding the field, but the model field's help text isn't shown using this approach. Thanks!

Comment: As a note (regarding help_text not showing): If you override the model field in the form the attributes you define within the Form are used instead of the ones of the Model, so you have to define help_text again for the field in the Form (if you manually define one).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. `__init__` doesn't have any kind of privileged access to attributes: anything you can do inside that method can also be done outside it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm specifying the `queryset` in `__init__` because when I specify it in a field, I override the `helptext` attribute I set in my model. I'm just wondering if I can define the `queryset` outside of `__init__` without overwriting any attributes.